# angular - how to set a enum params in interface

Tags: angular

I try to set a enum params in a interface, for example:

structure.ts

```
export enum Type {
    Edit = 'edit',
    Add = "add"
}

export interface Test {
    type: Type,
    name: String,
    id: String
}
```

component.ts:

```
import {Test, Type} from 'structure';

test: Test;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.test.type = Type.Edit
}
```

error message:

```
RROR TypeError: Cannot set property 'type' of undefined
```

If it is not a nested structure, it can work normally:

component.ts:

```
 type:Type;

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.type = Type.Add;
}
```

Comment: `test` is undefined when you try to set `test.type` - this is fundamental Javascript. What's your intention here?

Comment: Your test is not instantiated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not `initialize` for test property, should init it as

```
test: Test = {};
```

Stackbliz https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-check-mediaquery

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that error because your property isn't initialized. The proper way to do it and to avoid complaints from TypeScript:

```
test: Test;

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.test = { type: Type.Edit, name: 'Name', id: 'sqsqsqsqsqs' };
}
```

Don't use `String` (capital case) as a type in your interface. Use `string` (lowercase) instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
enum Type {
    Edit = 'edit',
    Add = "add"
}

export interface Test {
    type: Type,
    name: String,
    id: String
}
```

In component

```
test: Partial<Test>;

ngOninit() {
   this.test.type = Type.Add;
  }
```

Partial can be used it all values are not available initially for assignment